# Django Filter Buttons

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using Django-filter in a very standard way.

```
class TaksFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['lastUpdated']
```

But I want to create custom quick filter buttons. Like last 1 day and last 7 days which essentially run this query set.

```
task = Task.objects.filter(lastUpdated__range=["2016-12-09", "2016-12-10"])
```

Is this something that can be done with django-filter or do I need to create a standard POST or GET response?

**Solved**

Thanks Ivo Donchev for the help. Using your code I solved it like this. I didn't want to go down the route of class based views as I am using functions.

form.py

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
last_updated = django_filters.MethodFilter()

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ['lastUpdated']

def filter_last_updated(self, value, queryset):
        qs = queryset.filter(lastUpdated__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=value))
        return qs
```

view.py

```
def tasks(request):

    tasks = TaskFilter(request.GET, queryset=Task.objects.all())

    if request.method == "GET":    

        if '1' in request.GET:

            value = 1
            tasks = TaskFilter(request.GET, queryset=(TaskFilter.filter_last_updated(tasks, value, queryset=(Task.objects.all()))))

    context = {
    'tasks':tasks,
    }

return render(request, 'tasks.html', context)
```

I know I can streamline the view a little. Next task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with django filters using MethodFilter and implementing method named filter_your_filed_name like so:

```
class TaksFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    last_updated = django_filters.MethodFilter()
    class Meta:
        model = Task

    def filter_last_updated(self, queryset, value):
        qs = queryset.filter(...)
        # your custom logic here using the passed value
        return qs
```

In a tag in the template:
    "href='your-url.com?last_updated=some-value'"

And in the view:

```
class YourView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {k: v for (k, v) in self.request.GET.items()}
        qs = Task.objects.all()
        filter = TaskFilter(data, queryset=qs) # using the filter

        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added that bit but how would I link it to a button on the template to link back to that filter query set?

Comment: Well you can use link it as get parameter:

Comment: note that `MethodFilter` has been deprecated in favor of the `method` argument ([docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/migration.html#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method)).